# Почему не срабатывают скрипты при AJAX навигации?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

На сайте имеется навигация по страницам, которые подгружаются посредством AJAX
и есть такой скрипт:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  // no decimal places (default)
  $('.abbr-number').abbrNum();

  // decimal places as attribute
  $('.abbr-number-attr').abbrNum();

  // decimal places as option
  $('.abbr-number-opt').abbrNum({
    decPlaces: 2
  });
});
```

Проблема в том, что этот скрипт срабатывает только на первой странице.

Подскажите, пожалуйста, как подружить этот скрипт с AJAX?

И, если можно, желательно с примером моего кода.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Событие `$(document).ready` не срабатывает при ajax-запросах.

Возможный вариант решения:

1. Выделить тело функции `$(document).ready` в отдельную функцию
   (назовем ее, например, `formatNumbers`). Это необходимо для того,
   чтобы функцию можно было вызвать как из события $(document).ready,
   так и из события окончания ajax-операции:

```
    function formatNumbers() {
           // no decimal places (default)
           $('.abbr-number').abbrNum();

               // decimal places as attribute
               $('.abbr-number-attr').abbrNum();

               // decimal places as option
                $('.abbr-number-opt').abbrNum({
                  decPlaces: 2
               });
            };

     $(document).ready(function() {
       formatNumbers(); 
     });
```

2. Далее потребуется модификация процедур, отвечающих за аякс-загрузку данных.
   Так как в JQuery существует несколько вариантов аякс-загрузки данных, однозначно ответить на вопрос, как именно требуется вносить правку, сложно.

Если, к примеру, загрузка происходит через реализацию, аналогичной следующей:

```
 $.ajax({
    url: "....",
  })
  .done(function(msg) {

  });
```

то для реализации вашей задачи в событие `done` нужно добавьте вызов `formatNumbers`:

```
$.ajax({
    url: "....",
 })
.done(function( msg ) {
   formatNumbers(); // Вызываем функцию по окончании ajax-загрузки данных
});
```

Альтернативный вариант — подписка на глобальное событие выполнения всех (в пределах сайта) аякс-запросов.

Этот вариант можно использовать только в крайнем случае *(например, если по какой-либо причине вмешательство в скрипты невозможно и сами скрипты не предоставляют интерфейсы работы с аякс-событиями)*, так как этот вариант, без дополнительной адаптации, может внести нежелательные изменения в логику работы всего сайта:

```
   $(document).ajaxSuccess(function() {
      formatNumbers();
    });
```

Comment: Спасибо Павел, сработал ваш альтернативный вариант (глобальный), но как вы сказали он не желателен ((

Comment: Если второй вариант (через глобальный обработчик) отрабатывает нормально (т.е. обеспечивает нужный вам функционал и, при этом, не ломает существующий), то используйте, почему бы и нет? В принципе, существующая реализация `formatNumbers()`  не должна привести к каким-либо поломкам кода.